# Java DOM xml reader if xml is not correctly formatted

Tags: java, xml

I'm reading my XML files inside a folder which contains a bunch of these files, hence I'm not able to check each manually if the format is correct (based on XML standards (but they all were generated by XML generator, so a majority should be correct)).

I'm running my XML DOM reader in Java on this folder, which saves the data from these files, however, when I run into a wrong formatted file, I only get the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] file15209.xml:1:101: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/...
```

Is there any workaround for this issue or anything that would DOM offer for solving this? Or maybe the case of me missing some piece of information?

Comment: Have you tried catching this `SAXParseException`?

Comment: _Is there any workaround for this issue_ It's not clear to me what the _issue_ is. You have files that contain invalid XML. What should your _XML DOM reader in Java_ do when it tries to read a file that contains invalid XML? Do you simply want to stop reading that file and continue on to the next file?